# C++. How to replace anything inside brackets (and brackets) using std::regex?

Tags: c++, regex

I have a mathematical expression string and need to replace brackets and everything in it with spaces. I doing it in Visual Studio Express 2012.

Examples of input => output:

```
"(a+b)*c+(x+y)" => "     *c+     "
"a+b"           => "a+b"
"(a+b)"         => "     "
```

I have code, that replaces what I need, but it also replaces everything except `+`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

std::string foo(std::string input) {
    std::string output;
    std::regex r("\\([^()]+\\)|(([a-z]|\\*)+)");
    std::smatch m;
    while (std::regex_search(input, m, r)) {
        output += m.prefix();
        output += std::string(m[0].length(), ' '); //here finded parts is replacing
        input = m.suffix();
    }
    output += input;
    return output;
}

void test(const std::string &in, const std::string &expected_out) {
    std::string real_out = foo(in);
    if (real_out == expected_out) {
        std::cout << "PASS" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "FAIL: got \"" << real_out << "\" instead of \"" <<
            expected_out << "\"" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    test("", "");
    test("a", " ");
    test("a*b*c", "     ");
    test("a+b", " + ");
    test("(a+b*c)+x*y", "       +   ");
    test("(a+b*c)+x+y", "       + + ");
    test("a+b*c+(x+y)", " +   +     ");
        system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

In fact, I only need to fix the regular expression.

As standard regular expressions can not handle nested structures, i must get some details on tusk. So, you just can ignore this option.

Comment: Be careful though, standard regular expressions can not handle nested structures (like the last example you show).

Comment: Oh. My code also can't do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[^\n](?=(?:[^(\n]*\))|((?:[^()\n]*\([^()\n]*\))*[^\(\n]*\)))|\)
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `space`.

https://regex101.com/r/cA4wE0/18

Comment: @user3206223 lookahead is supported there right?Then rest all is same .Should work.Try `\\\` instead of `\\`